# Page title is showing auto-generated text instead of the real page title name using TestCafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have created a simple test via TestCafe which check that Google Home Page has appropriate page title. By page title here I meant title text which is located in `<head><title>Google</title></head>`
But when I run it locally via using `t.debug()` I see that page title shows random auto-generated text instead of a real page title.

Here is my test:

```
fixture("firstTest")
    .page("https://www.google.com")

test("home page should have a title", async t => {
    await t.debug()
        expect(await t.title).toEqual('Google')
    });
```

Error message is: `ReferenceError: expect is not defined`

Please share any ideas why this could happen.

[Google page title during the test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3Qth.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is valid. To run tests, TestCafe uses proxy to rewrite the URL (https://testcafe.io/documentation/402631/why-testcafe#page-proxying). Getting the page title using JavaScript will return the actual value.

See the example below:

```
import from 'testcafe';

fixture("firstTest")
   .page("https://www.google.com")

test("home page should have a title", async t => {
   await t.expect(Selector("title").innerText).eql('Google')
});
```